# tf208093 excel reporting from TFS 2012

Tags: reporting-services

I have TFS2012 with MSSQL on my single server.

I am getting the following error in *Microsoft Excel*  to generating reports(graphs) for *TFS Queries* (from project admin account, connection by the network).

> TF208093: You cannot use work item queries to generate reports in Excel on this server because it is not configured for reporting

At the same time there is NO error when i connect with windows server admin credentionals

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try use http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/ to check the users permissions in SSRS.

Comment: there are only permissions in projects. The user that have a problem have all roles in column reporting services roles